# Python - how to stop a function being called many times when its already executing?

Tags: python-3.x

```
                h_error = abs(180 - current_pos)

                if custom_tracker and h_error > 40:
                    if no_rot_in_progress:
                        if current_pos < 140:
                            no_rot_in_progress = False
                            rot_cen = (180 - current_pos) * 22
                            print('rotation time required ' + str(rot_cen))
                            turn_left_ptz = muterun_js('onvif_movement/turn_left.js', str(rot_cen))

                            if turn_left_ptz.exitcode == 0:
                                print('Custom Tracker - Turned Left')
                                no_rot_in_progress = True
                                # print(response.stdout)
                            else:
                                print('failed left')
```

There is a time gap between where this actually finishes with exit_code and the time taken to rotate the camera. So this turn_left_ptz javascript gets called multiple times because of that.

I need to find a way to stop going into this movement function when there is an active camera movement which is not finished.

Eg: The script registers it self finished after 1 second but there it will take the amount of time taken in rot_cen ( say 5 seconds) to actually move the camera.

sleep function causes whole script to be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

used python timers.

```
                            if start_timer is None:
                                start_timer = timer()

                            turn_left_ptz = muterun_js('onvif_movement/turn_right.js', str(rot_cen))

                            custom_sync = True
                            rot_cen_in_sec = int(rot_cen / 1000)
                            time_required = rot_cen_in_sec + 3

                            end_timer = timer()
                            timer_diff = int(end_timer - start_timer)

                            if timer_diff >= time_required:
                                custom_sync = True
                            else:
                                custom_sync = False

                            if custom_sync:
                                start_timer = None
                                custom_sync_main = True
                            else:
                                custom_sync_main = False
```